# Difference between чем and чём

Tags: произношение

From what I understand, **чем** is used for the instrumental case and **чём** is for the prepositional case. I have listened to an audio recording of both and they were pronounced the same way. Is that true? I thought they were pronounced **chyem** and **chyom** respectively.

*No, I do not have access to a native speaker, nor will I ever have access, so please don't ask. Thank you.*

Comment: Can you provide the text that was recoded? I cannot imagine them being pronounced the same way; maybe it was чем/чём in both of the cases in the text?

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy Hopefully no one shames me for this, but I listened to google translate. Not a good source, but just about the only one I have. I entered "with what" in hopes it would use the correct form, but it most likely did not. Wasn't sure though.

Comment: We have a number of posts about letter Ё here: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%91 I think you might find them useful.

Comment: @Artemix Yes I was confused by the audio clips I heard and their being the same. I think it was because it thought I was typing чём without the dots above the е. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, Google translate pronounces an isolated *чем* or *с чем* (with е, not ё) [as *чём*](https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/with%20what). This is definitely incorrect. The phrase *["Лучше поздно, чем никогда"](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0)*, however, is pronounced correctly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I always thought twice about using GT, but now I will think thrice haha.

Answer (score 1):

oh, there is a problem with a letter 'ё'
somebody trys to erase that letter from russian alphabet and history, and there was a rumor about try to make any law to change ё on е.
but anyway, this is a different sounds, and letters too.
чем and чём is two diffent words.
о чём ты говоришь? what do you talking about? a subject
чем ты это докажешь? how will you prove that? a property

Comment: Yeah I tried to enter in the translate "с чем" so that it would see I'm using the instrumental and not prepositional, but it didn't recognize it :/

Comment: с чем - is : with what? and you can't use " с чём ",  because  of  difference in sounds :  е  sounds like " и - е "

Comment: yes that's why I tried to use "с" was to make it recognize the case :)

Comment: с чем - is : with what? and you can't use " с чём ",  because  of  difference in sounds :  е  is sounds like " и - е " , and  ё is sounds like " й - о ". and also google speaker system displays these sounds differently, in 1st case almoust right, in 2nd case totally incorrect ( it's when you hear them as the same ), and it depends on what order words will appear, with ё first, or with е first. so  should try it by yourself to see.

Comment: and yes - you've made it right! smart move! now I see))